# Upgrading to new firebase console

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have recently migrated my app to new Firebase console without any SDK changes and my password authentication is getting failed.

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must us the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth
```

I currently do not want to migrate to 3.0.

As stated in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) "Your applications and the existing SDKs will continue to work" without SDK changes.

Comment: Got it! I was doing wrong, i was not migrating my original project was testing by creating replica in new firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I was doing wrong, i was not migrating my original project was testing by creating replica in new firebase console